# Change url when calling other servlet

Tags: servlets

I have 2 servlet: **Login** and **Admin**. After login, I wanna go to admin page.

Login

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if ("admin".equals(username)) {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin");
        request.setAttribute("param1", "value1");
        request.setAttribute("param2", "value2");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Admin

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/admin.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

The result is

> http://localhost:8080/app-servlets/login

What I want

> http://localhost:8080/app-servlets/admin

The reason why the url does not change is because i use **forward**. But I want to pass some parameters to jsp page, so I can't use **sendRedirect** in this case.

What should I do?

Comment: I suggest you to use login doGet() for displaying the login page, and validate the credentials in admin doPost(),this way you can get the url you need

Comment: @MigratedPigeon I understand what you said but this is unrealistic. Login view should be handle by Login Servlet, not Admin Servlet. 
What if a normal user logging in?

Comment: did you try include instead of forward?

Comment: @MigratedPigeon Same result

Comment: i don't think you need "/admin" just mention it as "admin" in request dispatcher

Comment: @MigratedPigeon I had try this way and nothing different.

Comment: why not store the parameters as attributes in session/context??.This way you can use sendRedirect and recovers attributes wherever you want.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz Because I put my jsp pages into WEB-INF folder and I can't access it. 
By the way, If I put jsp page outside WEB-INF, now I can access it with sendRedirect but the url will be look like this "http://localhost:8080/app-servlets/pages/login.jsp".
I don't want to show the "pages" folder on url, I think nobody does that.

Answer (score 0):

Store the attributes you need in the HttpSession:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if ("admin".equals(username)) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("param1", "value1");
        session.setAttribute("param2", "value2");
        response.sendRedirect("/admin");
    }
}
```

These attributes will be accessible in the JSP to which the "admin" `doGet(...)` forwards and the URL bar will contain the desired:

> http://localhost:8080/app-servlets/admin